# How to determine the distance of slipping in a toppling body?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, rigid-body-dynamics

A body of known mass is connected to the top of a light rod which perpendicular to the floor. As the body starts to fall, the base of the rod slips before the edge of the mass comes in contact with the floor. Assuming that all variables are known (masses, height, friction coefficient, etc.), how would the distance of slipping before the mass comes in contact with the floor be calculated?[image: visual representation of question]

Comment: this looks like something to simulate in animation software, not something there is a neat formula for

Comment: Thanks, i'll try till the end of the day before giving up